# Help with URL link and list element and jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, url

I'm trying to get a list element to point to a URL. 
For some reason, it does not link (because of the id="mylink" inside a href). 
The jQuery loads up an image map perfectly when I rollover the list item. No worries here. Simply turing to make my a href work...

Can some please let me know why the URL is not working?

```
<script>$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
    fade: true,
    $('#mylink').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#mapbox').mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $('#mapbox').mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
});</script>
```

The list item:

```
 <li><a href="mylink/index.html" id="mylink">My Link</a></li><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

You are telling it NOT to allow the browser to continue loading the href that the link points to.

Comment: Chad, you're the man! This worked out perfectly! Will mark as the answer =) Thx for helping out

Answer (score 0):

I see three potential problems with your code:

1. Most importantly, it isn't syntactically valid.  Perhaps it's just a copy/paste error, but you have what appears to be an object property (`fade: true,`) as a statement, at which point the JS parser will fail.
2. Your `click` handler is preventing the default action of the link — following the URL — without attaching any other functionality to it, ensuring that nothing happens when the link is clicked.
3. Your `<script>` and `</script>` tags are on the same line as code.  This is generally best avoided.  (Historically, some browsers have had issues with this, though it may no longer be an issue.)